# Cast and Comparison expression in HQL

Tags: date, types, casting, comparison, hql

Dears, I want to get last 7 days records from my stats. There is a date column in my data, but its type is "int" e.g., 20190102

anyone can advise how to get last 7 days records from my stats?

Comment: Why are you storing your dates this way?  Why not use a proper date/timestamp column?

Comment: Its due to the data template being exported from the source.